# Add array of faces to BufferGeometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, vertices

Given a *BufferGeometry*, I can set its vertices from an array of type `Float32Array` like so:

```
geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
```

Is there a way to set the BufferGeometry's faces in a similar way using an array of type `Int32Array`? I want to avoid this:

```
geometry.faces.push(
  new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 2),
  new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 3),
  new THREE.Face3(1, 7, 3),
  new THREE.Face3(1, 5, 7),
  ...
);
```

Comment: You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html) helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, what you're looking for is `BufferGeometry.setIndex()`, which allows for vertices to be re-used across multiple triangles, as [outlined in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.index). And here's the [the official working demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_indexed).

You can essentially create an array, then push sets of 3 vertex indices (based on the order of your other attributes):

```
var indices = [];

indices.push( 0, 3, 2); // face one
indices.push( 0, 1, 3 ); // face two

geometry.setIndex( indices );
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks.

Comment: This works without creating a three buffer attribute before the array?